# How to Add an X to the end of a string with exactly 7 characters in excel

Tags: excel

For example

1234567  would become 1234567X

12345678 Would stay the same

1234     would stay the same

123456789 Would stay the same

But would need to do this to approximately 20 strings of numbers but only want the X added to those with exactly 7 characters and to leave the others unchanged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=A1&if(len(A1)=7,"X","")
```

Where A1 is the string you're checking

Quite simply - copy in A1, then check if length is 7. If it is, add an X. If not, add nothing.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was playing around with len just didn't know how to structure the formula.

Comment: Hi I have a follow up request. The previous answer has been working great but i've run into a slight issue.  

1234567 = 1234567X  this is working fine
But sometimes I have 2 numbers separated by a comma in the same cell but only want the first number to have the X if it has 7 characters
1234567,9876543  = 1234567X   (Right now I get 1234567, which is wrong)
12345678,9876543 = 12345678

Let me know if you need clarification

Comment: @Kombu =IFERROR(LEFT(A1,FIND(",",A1)-1),A1)&IF(LEN(IFERROR(LEFT(A1,FIND(",",A1)-1),A1))=7,"X","") - What I'm doing here is essentially the same logic, but both times I try looking for A1 I return all the text before the comma. As you can imagine, if there isn't a comma, it causes an error - which I check for and if the error is found, I just return the whole cell instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula:

```
=IF(LEN(A1)=7;CONCAT(A1;"X");A1)
```

You are telling Excel to check if the lenght of a cell in characters is equal to 7 (first parameter, `LEN(A1) =7`).

If the test condition is **true** the result will be a concatenation between the cell and the string "X" (second parameter, `CONCAT(A1;"X")` ).

If the test condition is **false**, the result will be equal to the cell value (no changes will be made, third parameter, `A1`))

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad it helped! If you want, please accept an answer. Have a nice day!